# File size in bytes is not equal to number of characters in UTF-8 encoded file

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

I try common lisp hunchentoot-test.

When i upload utf-8 text file with non-latin symbols the length of uploaded file increased. In finish file the additional byte for each non-latin symbol was inserted. I don't understand why. 
Last experiment was on just started ubuntu system on digitalocean.
Install emacs, clisp and slime. In swank execute:

(ql:quickload "hunchentoot")
(ql:quickload "hunchentoot-test")
(hunchentoot:start (make-instance 'hunchentoot:easy-acceptor :port 4242))

It is enough for seeing the problem on 127.0.0.1:4242/hunchentoot/test/upload.html

Answer (score 6):

> *When i upload utf-8 text file with non-latin symbols the length of uploaded file increased. In finish file the additional byte for each non-latin symbol was inserted. I don't understand why.*

According to the [Wikipedia article on UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (emphasis added):

> UTF-8 is a character encoding capable of encoding all possible characters, or code points, in Unicode. **The encoding is variable-length** and uses 8-bit code units. … UTF-8 encodes each of the 1,112,064 valid code points in the Unicode code space (1,114,112 code points minus 2,048 surrogate code points) **using one to four 8-bit bytes** (a group of 8 bits is known as an octet in the Unicode Standard). Code points with lower numerical values (i.e., earlier code positions in the Unicode character set, which tend to occur more frequently) are encoded using fewer bytes. **The first 128 characters of Unicode, which correspond one-to-one with ASCII, are encoded using a single octet with the same binary value as ASCII, making valid ASCII text valid UTF-8-encoded Unicode as well.**

This means that when you're restricting yourself to ASCII text, you'll be using one byte per character.  Once you leave the ASCII realm, however, you may be using more than one byte per character.  So, even though you're adding just one more character, you're adding more than one byte.  With UTF-8 you can't assume "one byte per character."